# Is there a simple, standard way to "new" and "delete" objects via an allocator?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, std

I gather that custom allocators can sometimes be trivial to add to a program--for instance, in some particular case it may be enough to simply replace the text `std::vector<int>` with `std::vector<int, SomeAllocator>` and recompile.

But what if I want to directly replace the standard memory management with that represented by a custom allocator in code that directly uses `new` and `delete`, like this:

```
class Thingy
{
    int whatever;
public:
    Thingy(int whatever) : whatever(whatever) {}
};

Thingy* thingy = new Thingy(77);
delete thingy;
```

I am new to allocators, but I guess I can accomplish that by calling four allocator methods:  one to allocate, one to construct, one to destroy, and one to deallocate.

```
SomeAllocatorForThingy a;
Thingy* thingy = a.allocate(1);
a.construct(thingy, 77);
a.destroy(thingy);
a.deallocate(thingy, 1);
```

Or something like that.  But I would rather do it in two commands, like I could with `new` and `delete`; and I would like to do it without having to add that extra `1` parameter repeatedly.

Does the standard library provide a standard way to do this already?  Something like:

```
Thingy* thingy = std::new_allocated_object<Thingy, SomeAllocatorForThingy>(77);
std::delete_allocated_object<SomeAllocatorForThingy>(thingy);
```

and maybe with some other forms for stateful allocators.

I don't anticipate having trouble writing my own functions for this purpose, but if standard ones already exist then I'd rather use those.

Comment: Do you want to control allocation/deallocation for a specific class, or do you want to control the allocation/deallocation globally?

Comment: I want the allocator to be used for the particular Thingy instances I specify, while others are instantiated in the default way, just as can be done with the STL container types (though admittedly those achieve this in a different way, by ALWAYS taking an allocator and just using a default one normally, while my example type Thingy knows nothing of allocators).

Comment: Hmm ok. Out of curiousity, what is the use case?

Comment: It is yet to be designed.  I have a program that may or may not need optimizing, but I'm mainly learning and exploring here.  I'm thinking about how memory pools and such could be used in my programs in the future, and trying to come up with a direct, easy way to replace the default memory management functionality within a set of expressions that I choose with whatever other management strategy I might specify.  Allocators seem to be designed for this purpose.

Comment: You might be interested in [P0211](http://wg21.link/p0211).

Comment: @mjwach it's rarely advisable to optimize for a what-if case, since you'll always be thinking of more and more abstractions to make things even more flexible. I like the template idea of your comment to my answer, you can always fall back to a default one there, if the usage of the class allows for that. Other than that, it's a bit hard to give you the perfect answer since we don't know exactly what you are trying to solve and how your code is currently designed.

Comment: Worst case, you can always create objects where you experience performance issues due to memory allocation via generic memory allocation functions from a specialized pool and placement new

Comment: @T.C. Yes, that's pretty much what I'm looking for, including both replacements for new and delete, and another thing I didn't ask for here but also wanted (that being features that make unique_ptr, make_unique, and allocators all neatly compatible with one another).  I guess I will now write my own things based partly on the code in that proposal.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `new` and `delete` operator as described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete). Then you can just keep on using `new` and `delete` as is, but you'll have control over the allocation and deallocation.

Example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
    }



    void *operator new(size_t size)
    {
        std::cout << "new(" << size << ")" << std::endl;
        return malloc(size);
    }

    void operator delete(void *ptr)
    {
        std::cout << "delete(" << ptr << ")" << std::endl;

        if(ptr)
            free(ptr);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo *bar = new Foo();
    delete bar;


    return 0;
}
```

Which will print something like this:

```
new(1)
Constructor
Destructor
delete(0x7fa72b6000a0)
```

Comment: If I understand right this would change behavior for ALL Thingy (or Foo) instances, whereas I want to specify my choice between normal memory management and allocator-mediated management in each "new"-like statement.  Also, if an allocator instance has internal state, then I guess I would have to use a static variable or something to let those two operators get at that instance?

Comment: @mjwach Yes, it's not a selective opt-in, if you override that operator it will be used. If you only need it for special cases, maybe a specialised class would be the better solution? Otherwise it will get messy quite fast, especially with regards to keeping track which allocator an object came from.

Comment: I suppose that if I wanted Thingy to REALLY act like std::vector with respect to allocators, then I should give it a template argument to represent an allocator type, and (if necessary) a member variable to hold or refer to an allocator instance.  Then these operators would be able to do what I am asking for.